# is there any endpoint in amazon sp api to get seller Id?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-selling-partner-api

I want to update the listing quantity on amazon through patchlistingItem API but it requires **SellerID** , I can't find any endpoint to get sellerId  (I have only a refresh token ) of sellers that are authorized with our website.
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-reference#patchlistingsitem

I have tried this endpoint but cant get sellerId
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/sellers-api-v1-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been having the exact same issue trying to find any information regarding how to get a seller's ID through the SP-API.

As far as I can see, the only way to programmatically get the seller's ID is during the app authorization process via oauth:

https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/selling-partner-appstore-authorization-workflow

It mentions in Step 4 that the redirect after authorization includes `selling_partner_id` as a query parameter. That is the seller account's ID.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any way to retrieve the seller ID after the fact. There is a Github issue regarding this missing feature but, unsurprisingly from Amazon, has not gotten very far:

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/492

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a tricky way to get SellerID using Amazon SP API.

You can use '**getMyFeesEstimateForASIN**' API endpoint under '**PRODUCT FEES API**' ie **POST /products/fees/v0/items/{Asin}/feesEstimate**.

link: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/product-fees-api-v0-reference#getmyfeesestimateforasin

You can make a POST request for any ASIN like:

```
{
  "FeesEstimateRequest": {
    "MarketplaceId": "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
    "IsAmazonFulfilled": true,
    "PriceToEstimateFees": {
      "ListingPrice": {
        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
        "Amount": 10
      },
      "Shipping": {
        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
        "Amount": 0
      }
    },
    "Identifier": "B08WJ81ZS1"
  }
}
```

and you will get an API Response containing 'SellerId' for the used refresh token in that API call. Here is an example of an API response:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "FeesEstimateResult": {
      "Status": "ClientError",
      "FeesEstimateIdentifier": {
        "MarketplaceId": "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
        "IdType": "ASIN",
        "SellerId": "A2VYDBAL8BMVQK",
        "SellerInputIdentifier": "B08WJ81ZS1",
        "IsAmazonFulfilled": true,
        "IdValue": "B08WJ81ZS1",
        "PriceToEstimateFees": {
          "ListingPrice": {
            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
            "Amount": 10
          },
          "Shipping": {
            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
            "Amount": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "Error": {
        "Type": "Sender",
        "Code": "InvalidParameterValue",
        "Message": "There is an client-side error. Please verify your inputs.",
        "Detail": [
          
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check the following JSON element in the above response:
**"payload.FeesEstimateResult.FeesEstimateIdentifier.SellerId"**

It will work for **Private and Public Developer (Both)**

You can confirm that Seller Name and address using this link with the above sellerId: https://www.amazon.com/sp?seller=A2VYDBAL8BMVQK